# Metropolis-Hastings on domain $(2, \infty)$

Tags: simulation, markov-chain-montecarlo, computational-statistics, metropolis-hastings

I'm trying to understand the Metropolis Hastings algorithm in depth by solving some exercise problems. On one of them, I'm asked to use MH to generate samples from

$$f(x) = c \frac{1}{\theta}e^{-\frac{x}{\theta}}, \quad x>2, \ \theta > 0$$

This deviates a bit from the other problems that I've come across and specifically in the followings aspects:

1. I cannot find a proposal function with the same domain. I thought I might use a similar exponential distribution as proposal but I don't know how to handle values generated on $(0, 2)$. Do I accept the previous valid sample again? Or do I just ignore the generated value and keep generating until I pull a valid one?
2. If I do use the exponential distribution as proposal $p$, then what is $p(x^{t+1} | x^{t})$? How do I make my exponential proposal dependent on the previous sample? I've seen problems with normal and uniform distributions, where you just center them on the previous sample. Centering the exponential on the previous sample doesn't sound like a good idea.